# Powershell opening file path with whitespaces

Tags: powershell, start-process

I'm my PS script I want to be able to run another script in another PS instance by doing the following:

```
$filepath = Resolve-Path "destruct.ps1"
    
start-process powershell.exe "$filepath"
```

`destruct.ps1` is in the same folder as this script.

However when running this script in a location which includes spaces (`"C:\My Scripts\"`) I will get the following error:

> The term 'C:\My' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file. Verify the term and try again.

I know by using a `'&'` with the Invoke-Expression method solves this problem, how can I do the same but by using the start-process method?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this:

```
 start-process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-file `"$filepath`""
```

edit after comments:

```
start-process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-file `"$($filepath.path)`""
```

side note:

`$filepath` is a `[pathinfo]` type and not a `[string]` type.

Comment: One more question! How do i carry parameters across using this method? I have $courseName i want to pass to the $filePath script which has a courseName parameter. I tried the following but it doesnt work: start-process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-file `"$($filepath.path) `"-courseName $courseName"

Comment: @user3402227 try to post a new question, for me it seem to works, but comments are not ideal to post code..

Answer (score 16):

You can add escaped double quotes so that you pass a quoted argument:

```
 "`"$filepath`""
```

Comment: Another option would be to use single quotes on the "outside," such that double quotes will be treated as literals.

Comment: Then you get the double quotes, but $filepath doesn't expand. It will expand if you put it in single quotes inside of double quotes, but the command line doesn't like the single quotes.

Comment: Hey, Thanks very much for your help. Unfortunately this still doesnt do the trick? Having the $filepath without spaces works, with spaces does not...

Comment: @mjolinor um.. this way the `-file` parameter is for the start-process  cmdlet.

Comment: I would typically do: `'"{0}"' -f $FilePath`

Comment: That's another option.  Either way, you're going to have to get the file path double quoted in the argument list.

Answer (score 2):

I am answering here for a general scenario.

If you need to navigate to a folder for example `C:\Program Files` from the Powerhsell, the following command won't work as it has white space in between the path.

`cd C:\Program Files`

Instead embed the path with double quotes as like the below.

`cd "C:\Program Files"`

Answer (score 2):

In case you came across this issue looking for a solution using **PowerShell 7 (pwsh)**:

1. write the argument list as a single string with all parameters
2. wrap the script name with double quotes
3. wrap the parameter string with single quotes and parantheses

Basic example:

```
Start-Process pwsh -ArgumentList ('"path/to/my script with spaces.ps1"')
```

Example with an additional switch:

```
Start-Process pwsh -ArgumentList ('-NoExit "path/to/my script with spaces.ps1"')
```

Example running the script as an administrator:

```
Start-Process -Verb runAs pwsh -ArgumentList ('-NoExit "path/to/my script with spaces.ps1"')
```

This is a workaround for issue https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576 that hasn't been resolved in over 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

File name might contain spaces, so preserve spaces in full path:
Notepad++ exec command:
"C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "& \"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)\""

same from command prompt:
"C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "& \"C:\a_work\Systems\name with spaces.ps1\""

Answer (score 0):

Just in case [string]$shipno (which is path & file name) comes in including spaces the following allows it to be passed to -FilePath successfully:

```
if ($shipno.contains(" ") -eq $true) {
   $shipno = """" + $shipno + """"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Windows 10, Powershell Version 5.1. I was having the same issue with spaces in the file path when attempting to execute PS1 scripts. In my case, I had one script that was calling another in the same folder. The purpose of the first script is to elevate the second script to admin privileges. The spaces were in the user's name on the computer, so that their desktop was something like "C:\Users\User Space Name\Desktop". I tried every suggestion across the internet, including the suggestions here and on other StackOverflow posts. NONE worked. I could get the scripts to run if I opened Powershell first, but I could not get them to run by double-clicking the file. I would always get errors in the form of "The term 'C:\Users\User' is not a recognized cmdlet..."

I found out that if you edit the registry entry for the file extension association to powershell, it will start working. The registry entry is as follows:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\powershell.exe\shell\open\command

Default Value: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "%1"

New Value: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "& "%1""

I'm not sure why this works but it does.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Example of Start-Process simple

```
$Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\New folder"        # Path with spaces
$ScriptName='toto.ps1'                           # Script name
$ScriptArgument="-ExecutionMode $ExecutionMode"  # Script arguments 
    
# Spaces and other characters escaped

$ArgumentList="$($Path.Replace(' ','` ').replace('(','`(').replace(')','`)'))" + "\$ScriptName" + " " + $ScriptArgument
  
# Start-Process  

Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -PassThru -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Example of Start-Process with Runas

```
$Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\New folder"        # Path with spaces
$ScriptName='toto.ps1'                           # Script name
$ScriptArgument="-ExecutionMode $ExecutionMode"  # Script arguments 
      
# Spaces and other characters escaped
   
$Path="$($Path.Replace(' ','` ').replace('(','`(').replace(')','`)'))" 
    
# Start-Process

$Command="-Command Set-Location $Path;$Path\$ScriptName $ScriptArgument" 
$Command="-Command Start-Process -FilePath Powershell.exe '$Command' -Verb RunAs -PassThru -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden"
      
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe $Command -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```